# Finding boundaries for an integral

Tags: integration

> Prove: $$\frac{1}{49}\cdot\left(e^3-e^ {- 2 }\right)\leq\int_{-2}^{3} \frac{e^{x}}{\left(8-x\right)\,\left(x+6\right)}\mathrm{d}x\leq \frac{1}{40}\cdot\left(e^3-e^ {- 2 }\right)$$

The integral is impossible to integrate ,the boundaries seems to be in form of: $\int_{-2}^{3}e^x\cdot g(x)$

How should I approach this? should I look at the min/max points of the function and look at the value it get in $[-2,3]$?

Comment: For the time being, the integral *seems to be impossible to integrate*. Don't worry, sooner or later, you will learn that the antiderivative expresses in terms of some special functions. Cheers :-)

Comment: MMA says : Integral=$\frac{e^{14} (\text{Ei}(-10)-\text{Ei}(-5))-\text{Ei}(4)+\text{Ei}(9)}{14 e^6}$,where $\text{Ei}$ is exponential integral function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality I need is 
$$\min g(x)\cdot |f(x)|\leq g(x)\cdot|f(x)|\leq\max g(x)\cdot |f(x)|,$$
which in general holds without the absolute value iff $f$ is positive, because the signs in the - always true - inequality
$$\min g(x)\leq g(x)\leq\max g(x),$$
change "direction", if we multiply them with a negative number, and so in particular with some $f(x_0)<0.$

Exactly as you suggest: as $e^x$ is positive one has
$$\min_{x\in[-2,3]} g(x)\cdot \int_{-2}^3e^xdx\leq \int_{-2}^3e^xg(x)dx\leq  \max_{x\in[-2,3]} g(x)\cdot \int_{-2}^3e^xdx$$
So everything boils down to showing that

$$\min_{x\in[-2,3]}(8-x)(x+6)=40$$

and 
$$\max_{x\in[-2,3]}(8-x)(x+6)=49$$

which should be easy for you: the minimum is the vertex of the parabula, the maximum must be achieved on the boundary.

Comment: We are using the fact that $e^x$ is positive to build the inequalities?
shouldn't we integrate to get the max value of the function $g(x)$?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the explanation

Comment: If I try to do the same with $\int_{0}^{5} x^2dx$ finding min/max values of the function does not bound the integral $(=\frac{125}{3})$

Comment: of course it does... try choosing $g(x)=x$ or $g(x)=1$, you'll get the bounds $125/2$ and $125$ respectively

Comment: I need to look at $\int_{0}^{5}x^2\cdot x/1$?

Comment: Exactly. Without some $g$ no such extimate can exist

Comment: So If I look at $g(x)=x$ its min value is $0$ and max is $5$ so I get $5*\frac{5^3}{3}=\frac{625}{3}$

Comment: If you take $g(x)=x$, your new $f$ is $f(x)=x$. (This is my last comment, as this is not supposed to be a chat. In case formulate a new question :) )